# 'DataFrame' object is not callable in a ApplyResult reference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

I want to start by stating that I am aware that this error message was posted multiple times. But I cannot seem to understand how those posts apply to me. So I want to try my luck:

I have Dataframe "df" and I am trying to perform a parallel processing of subsets of that dataframe:

```
for i in range(1, 2):
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=4)
    async_result = pool.apply_async(helper.Helper.transform(df.copy(), i))
    lst.append(async_result)

results = []
for item in lst:
    currentitem = item.get()
    results.append(currentitem)
```

Helper Method:

```
@staticmethod
def transform(df, i):
    return df
```

So I usualle code in Java and for a class I need to do some stuff in python. I just dont understand why in this case I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Barry/file.py", line 28, in <module>
    currentitem = item.get()
  File "C:\Users\Barry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 768, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\Barry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

A print in the thread function or before creating the thread results in proper output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the line:

```
async_result = pool.apply_async(helper.Helper.transform(df.copy(), i))
```

The catch - you're calling the function 'transform' *before* passing it to `apply_async`. As a result, apply async receives a data frame, "thinks" it's a function, and tries to call it asynchronously. The result is the exception you're seeing, and this result is saved as part of the `AsyncResult` object.

To fix it just change this line to:

```
async_result = pool.apply_async(helper.Helper.transform, (df.copy(), i))
```

Note that `apply_async` gets two arguments - the function and the parameters to the function.